# fink doesn't list gtkmm2.4

Tags: gtk, gtkmm, fink

I'm trying to get started with gtkmm, and I'm using a mac. So I tried using fink to get it installed. Looking online, it [seems to be up to date](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/gtkmm2.4-dev), but when I check on the command line

```
fink list gtkmm
```

It only lists gtkmm2. I went ahead and tried that, but it really is the gtkmm 2.0 distribution. I'd really like to be up to date on this, not to mention the hello world example failed, and I think its because I'm not using 2.4.

How do I get fink to find and install gtkmm 2.4? I tried `fink selfupdate` and `apt-get update` to make sure that everything was up to date, but with no luck.

Comment: Sorry to comment on a random question, but could you please contact me? My username at gmail.

Comment: Unrelated comment 2: Remember [your popular answer to "Can a Programmer Become a Decent Graphic Designer?"](http://web.archive.org/web/20100813080556/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58807/can-a-programmer-become-a-decent-graphic-designer), which [was since deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58807/)? There's a [similar question on the Graphic Design SE site](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18630/): would be great if you could re-post that answer there so it can be linked to and seen. [(apparently Q can't be migrated)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178865/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like this was a fink 101 mistake. I was using the binary distribution of fink, and it was set to pull packages from point release. I guess if you switch to `fink selfupdate-cvs` or `fink selfupdate-rsync` it has access to the latest packages, and that was where gtkmm2.4 was.